# Mule ESB - SMTP Subject from a variable

Tags: java, mule, esb, anypoint-studio

I'm working on a flow to send an attached file to a mail.

```
<smtp:outbound-endpoint host="${instance.smtp.host}" port="${instance.smtp.port}" user="${instance.smtp.user}" password="${instance.smtp.password}" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="SMTP" connector-ref="SMTP" from="${instance.smtp.account}"  to="${instance.smtp.user}" subject="Transaction ID #[flowVars.transactionId]"/>
```

Everything is working well, I already have tested my flow and the mails are arriving to the specified mail address, however, I'm trying to modify the subject dynamically, using a value stored in a variable, and then the problem appears, seems like it's not possible to use my expression to set the subject's mail.

```
subject="Transaction ID #[flowVars.transactionId]"
```

This is the error I'm getting.

```
Root Exception stack trace:
```

[Error: unresolvable property or identifier: Transaction]
[Near : {... Transaction ID #[flowVars.tran ....}]
             ^

Do you have any clue about this problem or how can I fix it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to rearrange the expression so all of it is within the #[....]

```
subject="#['Transaction ID ' + flowVars.transactionId]"
```

Some fields get parsed as MEL expressions and some are more like templated strings that allow expression substitutions.

(One of Mule's annoyances)

Comment: I changed my expression as you said and it's working now, thank you so much!

Comment: I am also trying the same with this `<smtp:outbound-endpoint host="${smtp.host}" port="${smtp.port}" to="${to.address}" subject="#['Error: '+ flowVars.errorMessage +' CorrelationID:' + message.id]" responseTimeout="${smtp.outbound.response.timeout}" connector-ref="smtp-config" doc:name="SMTP outbound endpoint" from="${from.address}">`  I am able to get the message.id value, but getting `null` for `flowVars.errorMessage`

Comment: @Ravibeli As we can't see the preceding config , I assume you are sure that errorMessage is being set...Try using the ` flowVars['errorMessage'] ` syntax, i've found the dot operator in Mule/MEL troublesome. If that doesn't work, create a new Question here and show some more code or complete case.

Comment: Thanks for addressing @Mesh. I addresses the issue. I am using `#[sessionVars.emailSubject]` in subject line, and `emailSubject` populating value for variable before triggering email notification flow.

Answer (score 0):

Please debug the application and test if your flow variable for "transactionId" is being set before reaching to the SMTP message source.

Comment: Thanks for the helping, Yes, I did it, also I used a logger component, even with the same expression - #[flowVars.transactionId] - and the value is being stored correctly.

Comment: Can you attach the complete log to see more details on it.

Comment: I changed the expression by this one -  subject="#['Transaction ID ' + flowVars.transactionId]" - and it´s working now, thanks for your help!